# Unknown column 'check_in_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, database

Anyone able to help me? I want to know what does this mean.

Unknown column 'check_in_id' in 'where clause'

```
$query = "UPDATE guest SET guest_id = '" . $guest_id . "' , room_no = '" . $room_no . "' ,         arrival_date = '" . $arrival_date . "' , numberOfNights = '" . $numberOfNights . "' , reservationId = '" . $reservationId . "' , numberOfRooms = '" . $numberOfRooms . "' , numberOfGuests = '" . $numberOfGuests . "' , roomType = '" . $roomType . "' WHERE check_in_id = '" . $check_in_id . "'";
```

Thanks!

Comment: It means there is no such column in a table.

Comment: It means: "Unknown column 'check_in_id' in 'where clause"

Comment: SAuch a column is not avaialble in your table.might be spelling mistake (checkInId)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your table structure and make sure that the `check_in_id` field exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your **Table Structure**.

1. Such a column is not available in your table.
2. Otherwise your table column is not capital.
3. Both points are not valid then use can add new column **'check_in_id'** in your table.